# Why is this SQLite query not letting me cast the integer and subtract?

Tags: sqlite, azure, timezone, cortana-intelligence, azure-machine-learning-service

I have multiple columns in Azure Machine Learning that each have an hour, year, day, minute, etc for a date. I need to convert this hour from UTC to EDT, and then make it a date string such as

> YYYY/MM/DD HH:SS

This way, I can do an inner join. I've tried using CAST, CONVERT, and other SQLite functions, but none of these combos work. Here is where I am now:

```
select *
CAST([Col11] as int) -4 as EDTHour

([Col8] || '/' || [Col9] || '/' || [Col10] || ' ' || EDTHour|| ':' || [Col12]) as WeatherTime from t1

select 'Time Stamp' as secondTableTime from t2

SELECT *
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2
ON t1.WeatherTime=t2.secondTableTime
```

However, It never lets me cast the varchar column Col11 to a integer or decimal. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you can use the column alias in your concatenation in another column.

Try this instead:

```
select ([Col8] || '/' || [Col9] || '/' || [Col10] || ' ' || (Cast([Col11] as int) - 4) || ':' || [Col12]) as WeatherTime
```

Maybe that will get you where you want to go.

Comment: I ended up having to do a hack around, using azure ML's module that redefines it as a int column versus a string. However, this answer looks like it could go somewhere.